# Why Firefox asking for the master password frequently?

Tags: firefox, password

I am using a master password to protect my saved password in Firefox.

However, Firefox is asking for the master password in approximately one hour periods.

Is this normal?

I thought it was normal to ask only when changing, adding, or try to see a saved password.

[image]

**Here some "about:config" values @Bruno Pereira asked:**

privacy.cpd.passwords = false
security.ask_for_password = 0
security.password_lifetime = 30
services.sync.engine.passwords = true
sync.log.logger.engine.passords = does not exist

**Installed add-ons:**

- Adblock Plus
- DownThemAll
- FlashGot
- Ubuntu Firefox Modifications

Comment: @Bruno Pereira, I have updated question and added information about what you asked.

Comment: @Bruno Pereira, sorry forgot to add add-on info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question asked over at [support.mozilla.com](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/791131). A couple of users feel that disabling sync or unregistering the particular machine from sync may help.